# hide paragraphs based on page

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a template based site which i have created using ASP. I have several paragraphs of content that needs to be not visible in some pages.

Eg:
home.asp
content: xyz

kind.asp
content: x

search.asp
content: xz

so when a user visits the site at home.asp the paragraphs XYZ needs to visible, and in kind.asp only X needs to be visible.

Can someone please suggest me how to do it in asp or javascript?

Comment: Need more information - what templating engine are you using? Why are you forced to have the same content on each page, which you then have to try and hide parts of? Why can't you just render only the content you need on the server?

Comment: I supposed he is using a self-made templating engine...

Comment: i am using a self-made templating engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a little generic script on the clientside could look like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if( ~location.pathname.indexOf( 'home.asp' ) ) {
        [].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'p:not(.xyz)', function( elem ) {
            elem.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
}, false);
```

Be aware that is just an example without browser-abstraction level. However, using jQuery this task becomes totally trivial:

```
$(function() {
    f( ~location.pathname.indexOf( 'home.asp' ) )
       $('p:not(.xyz)').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
<%
sub writeXYZ()
    Response.Write("<p>This is XYZ</p>")
end sub

If showXYZ Then
    writeXYZ()
End If
%>
```